First-Order Logic With Extensional Set Membership
It is common to sometimes present First-Order Logic with equality and sometimes without. Adding equality has some nice benefits, including the ability to talk about some number of things, e.g.
$\exists x \forall y (A(y) \leftrightarrow y=x)$
is enough to capture “exactly one thing is $A$.”
Given that, is there any use to going a “layer lower” and using a very weak notion of set membership to define equality? For example, one could add
$\forall x \forall y(\forall z (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \to \forall w (x \in w \to y \in w))$
to a standard presentation of FOL containing just logical symbols, variables, and set membership as the sole relation.
This way, notions like “every F is G” can be thought of in a set-theoretic way, namely $f \subseteq g$. By restricting the set-theoretic axioms to just extensionality, this system would basically serve as an absolutely general extensional set theory that is not interested so much in proving that sets exist, but what holds given that they do.
Is there any real benefit to something like this, or is set theory already more than enough? My main response to that would be that set theory is very much pointed at founding mathematics, whereas this is more designed to allow for quantification over “predicates” in a way that we already know makes sense.

I don't see how $\in$ makes sense in a language whose domain of discourse does not include sets.

@Karl I’m not saying it doesn’t.

Ah, it sounded like you were proposing a general alternative to equality in FOL, but rereading your last paragraph, I guess you're actually asking about a set theory with only extensionality.
